# PHP - Check for a value against a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$pover = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item_name] => "iPhone 5s Repair"
                [service_name] => "Touchscreen & LCD repair"
                [service_price] => 49.99
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [item_name] => "iPhone 5C Repair"
                [service_name] => "Power button replacement"
                [service_price] => 29.99
            )

    )
```

Now I have two values:

```
$item = 'iPhone 5s Repair';
$service = 'Touchscreen & LCD repair';
```

Now first I want to check if the item `$item` is in the array and then get the `service_price` and display it on the page. I have tried to search the array for `iPhone 5s Repair` using `array_search`:

```
$key = array_search($ititle, $pover);
echo $key;
```

But it does not output anything. Can anyone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: `array_search` doesn’t work that way for multi-dimensional arrays. You will have to loop through your outer array, and compare the `item_name` entry of each inner array. You can either do that loop explicitly yourself (`foreach`/`for`), or use a function like f.e. `array_filter`.

Comment: Should your values have quotes? `iPhone 5s Repair` => `"iPhone 5s Repair"`.

Comment: The values don't have quotes. I don't know why someone edited it. It's a dynamic array not a manually made one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search the array by yourself, there's no other way.

```
<?php

foreach ($pover as $delta => $record) {
  if ($record["item_name"] === $ititle) {
    $key = $delta;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried your example and it works. Thanks for that. Now how can I store the array number to a variable so that I can determine, which array number the value is in, so in this case [0] or 0. Thanks a lot again !

Comment: Expanded my answer, the key is stored in `$key`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping thru to search for your item.

```
// The value of what you're searching for 
$title = 'iPhone 5s Repair';

for($i=0;$i<count($pover);$i++) {
    $item = $pover[$i]['item_name'];

    // Foreach item in the array, see if it's one of the ones that you need
    if($title == $item) {
       $price = $pover[$i]['service_price'];
       $service = $pover[$i]['service_name'];

       echo "Found at ".$i."<br />";
       echo "The price for the ".$item." is ".$price."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop is not a bad idea to improve performance. But you'd have to be sure that the array is always full and you should write the loop differentely. `$c = count($a); for ($i = 0; $i < $c; ++$i) {}` that's how you should write `for` loops and always compare with three equal signs if you know that the type is equal (faster as well and more secure, like in JS).

Answer (score 0):

`array_search()` does **not** work for a multidimensional array I'm afraid. the best you can do is the browse the array by yourself.

```
foreach ($pover as $key => $value) {
  if ($value["item_name"] == "YOUR_TITLE") {
    /* Item found */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, an alternate option using the recent array_column() function added in PHP 5.5 (there is a userland implementation for older versions of PHP at https://github.com/ramsey/array_column):

```
<?php
function getPrice($item, $array) {
    $array  = array_values($array);
    $column = array_column($array, 'item_name');
    if (in_array($item, $column)) {
        return $array[array_search($item, $column)]['service_price'];
    }
    return false;
}

print getPrice($item, $pover);
```

Comment: This will be much slower, but for fun. ;)